# Painting upload on instagram Is it hram in islam

Tags: halal-haram

Aslama Lekkum,.. I am a girl, I make painting like cityscape, landscape and nature or even upload it on Instagram so in addition to Instagram post I can make painting reel ,,,,this is right in islam

Answer (score 0):

Waalaikumussalam Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuh, as long as it's not an animate creature that has eyes, it's able. Wallahua'lam.

````
٤- [عن وهب بن عبدالله السوائي أبي جحيفة:] رَأَيْتُ أبِي اشْتَرى عَبْدًا حَجّامًا، فَسَأَلْتُهُ فَقالَ: نَهى النبيُّ ﷺ عن ثَمَنِ الكَلْبِ وثَمَنِ الدَّمِ، ونَهى عَنِ الواشِمَةِ والمَوْشُومَةِ، وآكِلِ الرِّبا ومُوكِلِهِ، ولَعَنَ المُصَوِّرَ.
البخاري (ت ٢٥٦)، صحيح البخاري ٢٠٨٦  •  [صحيح]  •  شرح الحديث

'Abdallah b. Mas'ud told that he heard God’s messenger say, “Those who will receive the severest punishment from God will be the people who make representations of things.” (Al-musawwiruna. There is a difference of opinion as to whether this refers to those who make snch representations as idols to be worshipped, or whether the reference is to representations of living creatures in general.)
(Bukhari and Muslim.)```
````